# AS3 Flash - Get text between ; characters

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, tags, character

Can someone help me how can I get the text between ; characters?

14;original;6711039;2;original;65535;9;6711039;52377;34;original;original

I need this:

```
var tag1:Number = 14
var tag2:String = original
var tag3:String = 6711039
var tag4:Number = 2
var tag5:String = original
```

... etc

how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`String.split()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29), which takes a `String` and splits it into an array at a specific character.

```
var s:String = "14;original;6711039;2;original;65535;9;6711039;52377;34;original;original";
var a:Array = s.split(";");
var tag1:Number = a[0];
var tag2:String = a[1];
var tag3:String = a[2];
var tag4:Number = a[3];
var tag5:String = a[4];
```

Note: I didn't check if the tags are correctly aligned, so you may need to use different indexes.